# Compass and SASS: Nothing to compile error

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm getting so tired of this problem right now. I've been put off so many times trying to get this going. I feel this is my last attempt in solving what is wrong. Here goes:

**I install compass**

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install compass
```

**I create my test project (named test)**

```
compass create test
```

**That generates this**

```
directory test/ 
directory test/sass/ 
directory test/stylesheets/ 
   create test/config.rb 
   create test/sass/screen.scss 
   create test/sass/print.scss 
   create test/sass/ie.scss
```

**I try to compile the project**

```
compass compile [path/to/test]
```

All I get is this error message: "Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument."

I try to google the problem but I can't find anything to help me. Anyone here that knows what's going on? Am i missing something important?

Im running OSX 10.6.8

Comment: that really sounds like you're trying to compile with a wrong path. Can you add the folder structure?

Comment: Thanks Rito, but believe me, the path is not the issue here. Anyway, this is my path: /Users/patrik/\[Projects\]/\[LAB\]/\[Compass\]/test. "test" is the project directory created as above.

Comment: OMG... Just OMG. All this time of frustration and I just found out the problem lies in t the [] in my path. Great, but what a pain to change my file structures. :S

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check to see if you have special characters in your filepath. I had "[" and "]" wrapping a directory name. This apparently causes Compass to choke. Removing those fixed my issue.

Seeing as though there are lot's of different scenarios that lead to this same error message, it would seem that some additional info in the debugging output might be helpful. I spent a couple of hours on this, thinking it was my config.rb file! Oh well, hope this post saves someone else some time.

Comment: Thanks! This finally fixed it for me.

Comment: I triggered this earlier, without thinking about it all my SCSS files were [partials](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials) - the filenames all started with an underscore. Doh.

Answer (score 5):

Missing `config.rb` produces the same error. Create a minimal one in your basic sass directory containing just

```
sass_dir = '.'
```

Answer (score 2):

Carefully check the paths in your config.rb file. This error can be caused by any error in the path definitions that lead to a non-existent directory.