# How can I get Compass to work in Visual Studio via NuGet?

Tags: nuget, compass-sass

My developer friend who has the luxury of developing in a non-Windows environment has been raving about Compass. I finally decided I wanted to give it a try. I'm tired of trying to keep up with all of the intricacies of cross-browser CSS.

So, I found it on NuGet, and installed it.

I installs to my solutions root directory in the *packages* directory:

```
$(SolutionDir)packages\Ruby.Compass.0.12.2.3\
```

It comes with a Readme that states the following message:

> ## Ruby Compass v. 0.12.2
>
> Compass is installed in its own NuGet package dir, and available by
>   'compass' command in "packages\Ruby.Compass.0.12.2.3" folder.
>
> To compile Compass files during build, add the next line to the
>   project pre-build events:
>
> "$(SolutionDir)packages\Ruby.Compass.0.12.2.3\compass" compile
>   "$(ProjectDir)."

So, I placed the line in my pre-build events, saved, and tried to build my project. However, I get an error as follows:

> The command
>   ""$(SolutionDir)packages\Ruby.Compass.0.12.2.3\compass" compile "$(ProjectDir)."" exited with code 1.

***Notice: It actually shows the full path to the `ProjectDir` and `SolutionDir` as it's supposed too in the error message. I replaced them with the tokens to keep the project name unanimous.***

Let me mention that I tried variations of the suggestion pre-build line:

```
"$(SolutionDir)packages\Ruby.Compass.0.12.2.3\compass" compile "$(ProjectDir)"
"$(SolutionDir)packages\Ruby.Compass.0.12.2.3\compass" compile "$(ProjectDir)css"
"$(SolutionDir)packages\Ruby.Compass.0.12.2.3\compass" compile "$(ProjectDir)css\test.scss"
```

The first one just removed that trailing `.`. The second one pointed it to the directory where all my css files are stored. The third one pointed it to the exact file I was trying to compile was located.

I opened up `compass.cmd` which is the file it is calling, and it looks like the following:

```
@echo off
"%~dp0ruby\bin\compass" %*
```

I'm assuming this calls the compass file in the ruby/bin folder, which looks like this:

```
#!C:/downloads/ruby-2.0.0-p247-x64-mingw32/ruby-2.0.0-p247-x64-mingw32/bin/ruby.exe
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'compass' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'compass', version
load Gem.bin_path('compass', 'compass', version)
```

From there, I'm not sure what is going on. I'm not a Ruby person.

Is there an issue that I'm overlooking here?
Has anyone else been able to install Ruby.Compass via NuGet?
How can I get this working in Visual Studio without having to fight with Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://codewith.us/automating-css-generation-in-visual-studio-using-sasscompass/

"Note that, if there are issues with your SCSS files, you will receive some variation of the error below.

Error 36 The command "del "C:Projectspubliccss*.css" /S
compass compile "C:Projectspublic" --force" exited with code 1.

Open your Output window (click View -> Output or press Ctrl+W, O), and select “Build” in the “Show output from:” menu. Scroll up until you find your command in the log and you should get a little more insight into what portion of the command failed."

Comment: Cool. Now I see this message. *"1>  Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument."*

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262335/compass-and-sass-nothing-to-compile-error

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working with this link.